# d3 preventing drag on specific elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to draw few rectangles in d3. I have an array which holds JSON objects of rectangle properties.

```
var rectObj = {
    id : 'streams',
    x : 10,
    y : 10,
    height : 50,
    width : 100, 
    drag:'true'
};
```

Some rectangles have draggable='true', while the others have draggable='false'.

I want to draw all the rectangle in a single SVG. They way I do it is,

```
var rectangles = mainLayout
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(rectObjects)
            .enter()
            .append('rect');

rectangles
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("initial-x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("initial-y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height; })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .attr("fill", function () { return "white"; })
        .attr("stroke", function () { return "black"; })
        .style("stroke-width", function() { return "1 px"; })
        .attr("draggable",function(d){return d.drag;})
        .call(dragStream)
;
```

On the dragStream, I want to stop the drag function from executing. That is, those rectangle should not do anything on drag.

```
var dragStream= d3.behavior.drag()
                    .on('dragstart', function(){
                        console.log('drg' + d3.select(this).attr('draggable'));
                        if(d3.select(this).attr('draggable') == 'false'){
                           // what should I do here ? 
                        }
                    })
            .on('drag', move /* this function is defined and works well*/)
            .on('dragend', function(){ // I do some stuff here

   });
```

What should I do to get the above requirement?

Comment: you need to differentiate in the `drag` event, not `dragstart`.  `.on('drag', function(d, i) { if(d3.select(this).datum().drag) move.call(this, d, i); })`.  And if you use `.dataum()`. then you don't need to write any attributes.

Comment: I don't understand the usage of datum(). can you please explain how I can use it to suit my requirement?

Comment: What do you mean? I explained already in my comment... try it and see.

Comment: Ok good, I explained a bit more in an answer below,can you  please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate in the drag event, not dragstart.

```
.on('drag', function(d, i) { if(d3.select(this).datum().drag) move.call(this, d, i); }).
```

And if you use `.datum()`. then you don't need to write any attributes. When d3 binds data to the selection it is stored on the DOM element, you can access it using `.datum()`. The value returned by this is a reference to the data array object so you can access the `drag` property there.